# URL rewrite function and pagination with year in the url

Tags: pagination, url-rewriting

**UPDATE**

No more 404 errors. Part of the problem was I using a reserved variable (year, doh!) so i changed a couple of things around and i have this almost fully working.

I've made very good progress since my last comment.  I changed how I was sending the year to the page.  Now my URLs in the menu are using a query string and they look like this:

> domain.com/our-company/newsroom/?articleyear=2014

And if I use the pagination at the bottom of the news page the URLs look like this:

> domain.com/our-company/newsroom/page/2/?articleyear=2013

I would love to change the url structure to something more like this:

> domain.com/our-company/newsroom/2013/page/2/

OR

> domain.com/our-company/newsroom/articleyear/2013/page/2/

Whichever makes the most sense based on my url structure.

Is there a rewrite rule I can use to make Wordpress understand the order I want the numbers to occur and have the article year right after /newsroom/ and the pagination occur at the very end?  I haven't written too many rewrite_rules, so a little assist with that would mucho helpful.

Am i thinking of this the right way?

Comment: the issue isn't with the function that generates pagination links, it's the fact that you don't have a rewrite rule to handle those incoming requests. how do you currently handle the incoming requests without page numbers?

Comment: aah ok, maybe i was mixed up with what the function was doing. You are right, that is only outputting the pagination links.  I suppose that is what I need.  I need a rewrite rule if page numbers exist.  With no page numbers its just a standard wordpress page and I am chopping up the url to get the 2013 from the url and then passing that to a variable and sending the variable to the query_posts to query news items by year.